# Why is $f:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ a local diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry

An example in my book says that $f:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ defined by $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ is a local but not global diffeomorphism.

By the inverse function theorem, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism if the determinant of $df_x$ is nonzero.

I must be doing something wrong. Isn't
$$
df_x=\begin{bmatrix} -\sin x \\ \cos x\end{bmatrix}?
$$

I was expecting a square matrix in order to take the determinant.

Comment: You've written $df_x$ for a map from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$.  You'll need to use 1-dimensional coordinates on $S^1$.

Comment: @MartianInvader Does that mean something like $f(t)=e^{it}$, so $df_x=ie^{ix}\neq 0$? for all $x$?

Comment: It almost seems that to get $1$-dimensional coordinates on $S^1$, you already have the construction of your local homeomorphism.

Comment: If you think it's ok to use $i$ here, I'd go back and double-check the definition of a differentiable manifold.

Comment: If you've established that $S^1$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$, then you have local slice coordinates $(r,\theta)$ so that $S^1 = \{r = 1\}$ and $\theta$ is a chart on $S^1$. In this local coordinate system $f$ has a very simple expression.

Comment: You should probably tell us your book's definition of the smooth structure on $S^1$.

Answer (score 4):

The map $f$ is smooth and the derivative at a point is an injective linear map. Restricting the codomain of derivative to the tangent space to a point on the circle, the derivative becomes a linear isomorphism.

Inverse function theorem of smooth manifold applies and you obtain that $f$ is really a local diffeomorphism.

**Edit**: To answer @Idonotknow's questions all at once.

1. The map $f$ is not a global diffeomorphism for an obvious reason: the map is not injective as $f(x)=f(x+2\pi n)$ for all integers $n$ and all real numbers $x$.
2. If you view the map as $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$, the derivative at $x$ would be given by the linear transformation represented by the Jacobian matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}-\sin x\\\cos x\end{bmatrix}$$ just as what OP found.
3. You check the above linear map's injectivity by letting it act on a nonzero vector $c\in\Bbb R$ (view it as a vector in the vector space $\Bbb R$), giving the nonzero vector $$c\begin{bmatrix}-\sin x\\\cos x\end{bmatrix}.$$ You check that is vector is nonzero, by calculating its inner product with itself: $$c\begin{bmatrix}-\sin x&\cos x\end{bmatrix}c\begin{bmatrix}-\sin x\\\cos x\end{bmatrix}=c^2\not=0.$$
4. Viewing $f$ as a maps $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$, the derivative at a point $x\in\Bbb R$ is a map between the tangent spaces $df_x:T_x\Bbb R\to T_{f(x)}\Bbb R^2$. What I mean by restricting the codomain, is that we choose the subspace $T_{f(x)}S^1$ of $T_{f(x)}\Bbb R^2$, and restrict the codomain to $T_{f(x)}S^1$. You can do so, because the image of $f$, by definition, is on $S^1$ only.

Comment: And why it is not global?

Comment: Also what is the jacobian matrix for the above mapping?

Comment: why the derivative at a point is an injective linear map?

Comment: and why we restrict the codomain of the derivative to only one point on the circle?

Comment: @Idonotknow see the edit. I try to answer all your questions.